# Primefaces fileupload resets on ajax update

Tags: ajax, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I'm doing a multiple record editing in primefaces datatable, in the record editing there is file upload, which resets when the user presses the "add" button

The jsf code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:dataTable var="file" value="#{fileUpload.files}" id="uploadTable">
                <p:column>
                    <p:inputText value="#{file.id}"/>
                    <p:inputText value="#{file.name}"/>
                    <p:fileUpload value="#{file.file}" mode="simple"/> 
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
            <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{fileUpload.add}" update="uploadTable" />
            <p:commandButton action="#{fileUpload.submit}" value="Submit" ajax="false" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

Here's the controller:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "fileUpload")
@ViewScoped
public class DummyFileUpload implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<File> files;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        files = new ArrayList<DummyFileUpload.File>();
    }

    public void submit() {
        // submit
    }

    public void add() {
        files.add(new File());
    }

    public List<File> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public void setFiles(List<File> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public class File implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2685385696849425824L;
        private String id;
        private String name;
        private UploadedFile file;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public UploadedFile getFile() {
            return file;
        }
        public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
            this.file = file;
        }
    }

}
```

The file upload control is reset when I do ajax call, I know it's a normal behavior but I'm asking if there's a known workaround for this situation and what could be the best practices for a complex business like this ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be avoided by changing the file upload tag to the following:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUpload.add}" mode="advanced" />
```

This way the `Add` and `Submit` buttons as well as the AJAX update are not needed as the advanced version of the file upload will provide the same functionality.

In addition, in your `DummyFileUpload` bean you wall have to change the `add` function:

```
public void add(FileUploadEvent event) {
    files.add(event.getFile());
}
```

Comment: you didn't get the File Object I made down the controller, it's a custom list not the primefaces File